# Bigcommerce Process Payment with api 401 error with code 10001

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bigcommerce

i just started working with bigcommrce payment API and unable to solve the error 401 unauthorized.

here is the sample data i have tried

```
{
 "payment": {
 "instrument": {},
 "payment_method_id": "cod",
 "amount": 81,
 "currency_code": "PKR"
 }
}
```

and

```
{
"payment": {
"instrument": {
  "type": "card",
  "number": "4111111111111111",
  "cardholder_name": "BP",
  "expiry_month": 12,
  "expiry_year": 2020,
  "verification_value": "411"
  },
 "payment_method_id": "authorizenet.card",
 "save_instrument": true
 }
}
```

but still getting the response of 401
I have set the authorization token (Payment Access Token) already with the other two headers.

Comment: Are you also passing X-Auth-Client and X-Auth-Token headers? You should have those 2 in addition to the Authorization header with the payment access token, Accept, and Content-Type. So 5 headers all together.

Comment: i passed all 5 headers, but still not working

Answer (score 2):

One likely cause of a 401 is the formatting of the payment access token header. It needs to be:

`Authorization: PAT token.goes.here`, with PAT in all caps and a space between the word PAT and the token. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, but how can i process offline methods? for offline methods it is giving this error

{
"code": 10001,
"errors": {
"payment.instrument.type": "Type is invalid."
},
"id": "831d27ba-55f8-4b37-9add-d76c2c71ed26",
"status": 422,
"title": "Missing or incorrect required fields.",
"type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes"
}

Comment: Offline payment methods aren't supported in the Payments API (we've opened a ticket to get this added to the docs). Since offline methods usually work by allowing an order to be placed without collecting a payment, you could handle this by creating the order via the Checkout API and then using the v2 Orders API to update the status to Awaiting Payment. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-checkout-api/checkout/createanorder https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/updateanorder

Comment: It is not working for test gateway, send the error " the payment was declined "